# Sort Function not working in Python

Tags: python, sorting, typeerror

I'm trying to get a sort by genre function to work with some python code, but I just can't seem to get it working. Currently, my sort function gets a TypeError stating that it takes exactly 2 arguments and there is only 1 given. I am getting the data from a json file.

Here is the beginning of my class:

```
import json
import operator 
from operator import itemgetter

class Movielist():

    dataFile = "mymoviedata.json"

    def __init__(self):
        print "Loading Program..."
        self.welcome()

    def loadData(self, dataFile):
        movieObject = []
        json_data=open(dataFile)

        movieObject = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
        return movieObject
```

Here is where I call the function

```
if option == "4":
    print self.sortByGenre()
```

Here is the function:

```
def sortByGenre(self, FoundMedia):
    sortedgenrelist = []
    sortedgenrelist = sorted(FoundMedia, key = itemgetter('genre'))
    return sortedgenrelist
```

Comment: Where's `FoundMedia` being passed? Eg `self.sortByGenre (something_missing_here)`

Comment: stop using tabs in Python. I know it's a pain, because all editors ship with tabs turned on, and programmers should not use tabs (or any other screwy spacing characters), but Python especially should not use tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
print self.sortByGenre()
```

Only passes 1 argument (`self`).  The function requires 2:

```
def sortByGenre(self, FoundMedia):
    ...
```

You should be passing another argument -- Some argument for `FoundMedia`.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: @user2896569 -- Not really.  It looks like `FoundMedia` is whatever you want to sort.  That's what you should be passing in there, but without knowing your code or your purposes, I don't think there's really much else I can do for you ...